# How to open PuTTY terminal directly, without configuration window?

Tags: ssh, putty

When you open PuTTY, the configuration window is shown:

[image]

Is there any way, to directly open its terminal, without that welcome (configuration) window? Where I can start typing the codes directly, like: `ssh user@example.com -p 80`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to skip PuTTY configuration/login window:

```
putty.exe user@host -P port
```

Or, to open your existing stored session:

```
putty.exe -load "stored session name"
```

---

If you are looking for a console SSH terminal, use [Plink from PuTTY package](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

It has the same command-line syntax as PuTTY and similar to OpenSSH `ssh`:

```
plink user@example.com -P port
```

(or again, you can use `-load`)

---

Or use OpenSSH `ssh` itself. There's now an official [Microsoft build of OpenSSH for Windows](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH).

On Windows 10 version 1803 or newer, you already have OpenSSH built-in. On older versions of Windows 10, it can be installed as an optional Windows feature. On older version of Windows, you can just extract the client-side tools from a .zip ([latest release](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases)), no installation is need.

Answer (score 4):

You can always save the definitions, and in recent versions of Windows (assumed), you can open these from the start menu.

Try `Putty -load *savedentry*`

Comment: +1. It's a shame this hasn't been chosen as the Answer as it seems universal across the connection types. Exactly what I was looking for to open a Serial terminal in one click.

Answer (score 3):

I see there's an accepted answer already, but if you're using Windows 10, the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is a great alternative.  You can put aliases in your .bashrc file, or you could reference the command history to reopen a previous connection.  You can also install [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) and have several connections open at once.

Comment: I was forgetting bash.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command.

```
 Putty -load "Saved Session's Name" 
 Example: Putty -load "Default Settings"
 Example: C:\putty.exe -load "Default Settings"
```

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-load

Answer (score 0):

You can open a session on Windows 10 without going through the putty welcome configuration window nor opening any command prompt window.

You can access your previous sessions (even pin one or many) by right clicking on the docked putty icon right from 'Recent Settings' contextual menu:

[image]